# Django app not able to find database engine when engine is specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have tried everything I can think of to run my initial migrations using `python manage.py migrate` and get my django app up. I am currently getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 24, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/dbshell.py", line 22, in handle
    connection.client.runshell()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 20, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

But this is the DATABASES var in my `settings.py` file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

- The db.sqlite3 file is at the location specified in the 'NAME' key.
- The app folder is in a subdirectory and uniquely named.
- The BASE_DIR var is constructed correctly and not causing the location string in the NAME key to be malformed.
- The `models.py` file is in the /app folder subdirectory.

I am completely out of ideas on how to get this to work and considering giving up on making this project altogether.

In case it helps here is my project tree

```
.
└── randoplant
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── manage.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    └── randoplant_app
        ├── admin.py
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── models.py
        ├── plant.py
        ├── __pycache__
        │   ├── admin.cpython-38.pyc
        │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
        │   ├── models.cpython-38.pyc
        │   ├── settings.cpython-38.pyc
        │   └── urls.cpython-38.pyc
        ├── settings.py
        ├── urls.py
        └── wsgi.py
```

Please help. I am running Django version 2.2.12 and I am in a WSL shell.

Comment: Can you upgrade your Django version?

Comment: @NixonSparrow Tried to do this just now and im still getting the same issue, I think im going to try to restart my whole app.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the name, you should do the following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

instead of giving a path to the database in the name field and it will automatically create a DB file for you,
You can read the [DATABASES settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases) in the official documentation for more information.

Comment: This didn't work - I tried your solution and got the same error. And it seems like the documentation is pretty much just asking for me to do what you describe here.

Comment: @Syllogism this is so weird, which OS do you use? are you sure sqlite3 installed on your OS? and after re-initializing, is the problem solved?

Comment: I did wind up fixing it after a complrte reset. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your project folder and is organized as recommended try using  the setting below or code below in your settings file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

Make sure that he BASE_DIR is defined in your settings file and imported the path library  as below:-

```
from pathlib import Path
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

But if you insist on using your previous database configuration file please make sure that the os and path module are imported.

Comment: Im using what the django startapp command initializes as the default sqlite3 database file for the project. So im not sure what you mean by saying "insisting on using a previous database configuration" - I changed nothing from the defaults.  I am simply trying to get my initial project to spin up successfully.

All the same - I tried implementing both of your changes individually and together and I got the same error.

Comment: Hello @Syllogism,  The insisting meant the configuration file if your not open to make edits suggested  however you did this  and didn't help please run migrations  directly from CMD instead of WSL, In CMD navigate to the folder where your project is saved make sure the setting file has `import os`  and `from pathlib import Path`

Answer (score 0):

I wound up copying out the code that I had in my project and re-initializing my project from the ground up.